# No overload matches this call. When using Object reduce callback in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've been stuck on this one for a few hours. I'm basically trying to create a function which turns a typescript type into a query string.  I started with an example I found online but I can't seem to get it working.  I'm seeing the error below.

```
import querystring from 'querystring';


 type AuthQuery = {
  code: string;
  timestamp: string;
  state: string;
  shop: string;
  host?: string;
  hmac?: string;
}

export function stringifyQuery(query: AuthQuery): string {
  const orderedObj = Object.keys(query)
    .sort((val1, val2) => val1.localeCompare(val2))
    .reduce((obj: Record<string, string | undefined>, key: keyof AuthQuery) => {
      obj[key] = query[key];
      return obj;
    }, {});
  return querystring.stringify(orderedObj);
}
```

And I get the following:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: string, currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => string, initialValue: string): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(obj: Record<string, string | undefined>, key: keyof AuthQuery) => Record<string, string | undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: string, currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => string'.
      Types of parameters 'obj' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string | undefined>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: Record<string, string | undefined>, currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => Record<string, string | undefined>, initialValue: Record<...>): Record<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(obj: Record<string, string | undefined>, key: keyof AuthQuery) => Record<string, string | undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: Record<string, string | undefined>, currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => Record<string, string | undefined>'.
      Types of parameters 'key' and 'currentValue' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof AuthQuery'.(2769)
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `reduce` here, and not doing so may markedly simplify things and help you get past the problem. Just use a loop. You're not doing functional programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions. And you're just passing the same object around all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `reduce` doesn't know that the array it's being called on is of `keyof AuthQuery` values; it thinks they're strings, because that's what `Object.keys` provides. You can't fix that by putting a type on the `key` parameter in the `reduce` call. Unfortunately, you have to use a type assertion, see where I created `sortedKeys` below (it doesn't have to be its own separate variable, but things were getting unwieldy):

```
export function stringifyQuery(query: AuthQuery): string {
    const sortedKeys = Object.keys(query)
        .sort((val1, val2) => val1.localeCompare(val2)) as (keyof AuthQuery)[];
    const orderedObj = sortedKeys
        .reduce((obj: Record<string, string | undefined>, key) => {
            obj[key] = query[key];
            return obj;
        }, {});
    return querystring.stringify(orderedObj);
}
```

I'd be tempted to move the `Record<string, string | undefined>` to the end as a type assertion on the `{}` seed value, like this:

```
export function stringifyQuery(query: AuthQuery): string {
    const sortedKeys = Object.keys(query)
        .sort((val1, val2) => val1.localeCompare(val2)) as (keyof AuthQuery)[];
    const orderedObj = sortedKeys
        .reduce((obj, key) => {
            obj[key] = query[key];
            return obj;
        }, {} as Record<string, string | undefined>);
    return querystring.stringify(orderedObj);
}
```

...but it works where you have it, so I've left it there.

I wouldn't use `reduce` for this, though, `reduce` only complicates this code. Here's a version using a simple loop:

```typescript
export function stringifyQuery(query: AuthQuery): string {
    const sortedKeys = Object.keys(query)
        .sort((val1, val2) => val1.localeCompare(val2)) as (keyof AuthQuery)[];
    const orderedObj: Record<string, string | undefined> = {};
    for (const key of sortedKeys) {
        orderedObj[key] = query[key];
    }
    return querystring.stringify(orderedObj);
}
```

---

You may be wondering why `Object.keys` isn't defined like this:

```typescript
function keys<T>(object: T): (keyof T)[];
```

Doing that was considered and rejected, apparently because of [this observation by Anders Hejlsberg](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208) (**hugely** respected language designer, creator of Turbo Pascal, chief architect of Delphi, lead architect of C#, and core developer of TypeScript):

> My reservations about `Object.keys` returning `(keyof T)[]` still hold. It makes sense only in the domain of type variables (i.e. `T` and `keyof T`). Once you move to the instantiated type world it degenerates because an object can (and often does) have more properties at run-time than are statically known at compile time. For example, imagine a type `Base` with just a few properties and a family of types derived from that. Calling `Object.keys` with a `Base` would return a `(keyof Base)[]` which is almost certainly wrong because an actual instance would be a derived object with more keys. It completely degenerates for type `{}` which could be any object but would return `never[]` for its keys.

If you wanted to ignore that sage wisdom — at your peril! — you could provide yourself a wrapper for it:

```typescript
function staticKeys<T>(object: T) {
    return Object.keys(object) as (keyof T)[];
}
```

Then getting the sorted keys for your operation above is `staticKeys(query).sort(/*...*/)` with no type assertion at the call site.

---

Side note re sorting the `Object.keys` array: Although objects do have a defined property order now, it's complicated (depends not only on when the properties were added, but on the actual values of the keys) and using it is rarely useful.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That makes more sense now. And I had a feeling i was just over complicating things.